# Connecting two transformers in parallel

Tags: transformer

I know that if you have two transformers connected in parallel that are of slightly different turns ratios, then there will be a circulating flow of VARs.

I also know that if you have two transformers that are mutually phase-shifted, you will have a circulating flow of watts.

My question is: what is a circulating flow of watts?  To my knowledge, having more VARs implies more current implies more losses.  But, having a circulating flow of watts seems like the exact same thing to me.

So what is a circulating flow of watts?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to draw a picture of what you mean to minimize ambiguity.

Comment: Hi Andy, I don't really know how to do that. But perhaps I can explain it a little bit better.

Imagine we have a three-phase grid and, connected to the grid, are two transformers in parallel.  One of the transformers is a normal transformer of turns ratio N; the other is a phase-shifting (a small phase-shift, for example) transformer also with turns ratio N. 
If ideal, identical transformers are placed in parallel, they will share the current equally; a different turns ratio causes VARs to circulate; a different phase causes Watts to circulate. What does "circulating Watts" mean?

Comment: I don't know what a small phase shifting transformer is and I don't follow your words. Draw a circuit and name the components.

Comment: Well, if you don't know what a phase-shifting transformer is, I'm not sure you can help me.  Thanks anyway!

Comment: A star delta transformer only shifts 30 degrees and 30 degrees aint small by any means. But you know best how to attract someone to answer your question.

Comment: Hi Andy, a quick google of "phase shifting transformer" would give you this page: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrature_booster.  I understand not everyone can answer the question, but if you can't (due to not having the requisite knowledge), then it's probably best not to post at all.

Comment: @Lerbi, I had never heard of VARs flow due to differences in voltage and flux from W to differences in angle. But it seems to make sense to me, I remember the "Power Systems" Electrical Eng. discipline that dealt with modeling the power flow in electrical systems: the voltage levels define the reactive flow and with the angles it is possible to control the active power flow (as in a phase-shift transformer).

Answer (score 1):

"Power flow divides inversely with the relative impedances on a common base"
 [RUS Design guide for substations](https://www.rd.usda.gov/files/UEP_Bulletin_1724E-300.pdf) - section 5.2.7 - Parallel Operation of Transformers